# My API validation message in not working in Laravel 7.x

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-validation, validationerror

I have created messages for handling validation error but it's not working properly. I have used the validator method for handling errors. Following is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\CountryModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers;
use Validator;

class CountryController extends Controller
{
public function country(){
    return response()->json(CountryModel::get(), 200);}

public function countryByID($id){
    $country = CountryModel::find($id);
    if (is_null($country)) {
        return response()->json(["message" => "Record not found!"], 404);
    }
    return response()->json($country, 200);}

public function countrySave(Request $request){
    $rules = [
        'name'=>'required|min:3',
        'iso'=>'required|min:2|max:2',
        'dname'=>'required|min:3',
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
    }

    $country = CountryModel::create($request->all());
    return response()->json($country, 201);
}

public function countryUpdate(Request $request, $id){
    $country= CountryModel::find($id);
    if (is_null($country)) {
        return response()->json(["message" => "Record not found!"], 404);
    }
    $country->update($request->all());
    return response()->json($country, 200);
}

public function countryDelete(Request $request, $id){
    $country= CountryModel::find($id);
    if (is_null($country)) {
        return response()->json(["message" => "Record not found!"], 404);
    }
    $country->delete();
    return response()->json(null, 204);
}
}
```

Which method should I use for handling validation error and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: You make a validation inside your controller

Answer (score 0):

You should not use

```
$country = CountryModel::create($request->all());

$country->update($request->all());
```

while inserting or updating the model as it contains _token in the request.

Replace the above 2 lines with the below code

```
$country = CountryModel::create($request->only('name','iso','dname'));
                              or
$country = CountryModel::create($request->except('_token'));


$country->update($request->only('name','iso','dname'));
                              or
$country->update($request->except('_token'));
```